# Pushpins clustering in universal windows apps

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I'm new to UWA development and Microsoft hadn't provided any documentation about this. I was just wondering if any one knows how to make multiple pushpins on a map cluster together if there are more of them close together?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature to cluster pushpin in the Bing Maps SDK but you can easily do it on your own.

Here is a great example with full source code using MVVM.

https://havefuncoding.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/clustering-pushpin-and-mapicon-with-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1/

There's also a library on Codeplex which includes a clustering features

https://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bing%20Maps%20Clustering%20Functionality